# swift can't call isKindOfClass with String

Tags: ios, string, swift

I have

```
let fieldValue: AnyObject?
```

if I want to check if it's NSString, it's ok:

```
fieldValue!.isKindOfClass(NSString)
```

But when I try to check if it's String, it give the error:

```
fieldValue!.isKindOfClass(String)
Cannot call value of non-function type '((AnyClass) -> Bool)!'
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

`isKindOfClass()` works only with classes that are subclass of `NSObject`.

You can use `fieldValue is String`.

```
if fieldValue is String {
  // do something with string
}
```

Answer (score 5):

use **'is'**

```
if fieldValue is String {
//
}
```

Answer (score -3):

you can check if it's a string by doing something like this:

```
var uiasd = [AnyObject]()

uiasd = ["asd", "asdf"]

if uiasd[0] .respondsToSelector("stringByAppendingFormat:") {
    println("this is a string")
}
```

this works too now that you've edited your question:

```
var uiasd: AnyObject? 

uiasd = "asdf"

if uiasd! .respondsToSelector("stringByAppendingFormat:") {
    println("asdfasdfkjgkhkjhkjhkjhkj")
}
```

Comment: "`respondsToSelector("stringByAppendingFormat:")`" is not at all intuitive or safe. `is String` is the appropriate solution to OP's question.

Comment: Sure. `class C { @objc func stringByAppendingFormat(_: Int) { } }`

Comment: that's not intuitive, JtBandes, and as such, that's not a valid answer

Comment: and, in swift, it's still a no go, it's not responding.

Comment: it would crash with an empty array or if input is nil at the second one

Comment: it would? or it does, have you tired this?

Comment: i don't post code unless I try it first, this isn't theoretical

Comment: just dropped my "unsafe" solution into two very popular, high production apps to prove my point, I'm running 90% of all objects through the if/then statement. Can't wait for my apps to fail the the 100s of thousands of users who use it. I'll keep you folks posted since you what's best.

Comment: 4 million server requests later and still no issues, I wonder if in fact I'm not being as unsafe as I need to be, any suggestions will be well received, I really want to lock down what you were saying about safety but I can seem to make my solution NOT working. If there's a book you have that I can read to get up to your level, then please let me know, but for now, LOL.